# Hive query on emp table which displays ename,sal of those who are working as salesman and sal>max(sal) of clerk

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hive environment, I want to find those employees who are working as salesman and also whose salary grater than maximum salary of  all clerks. I can write a query in SQL but I can't write it in hive.

Here you can find emp table that exactly I used.

[image]

Comment: *"I can write a query in SQL"*.  Please post that query and explain what isn't working in Hive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select tempemp.ename,tempemp.sal from emp tempemp,(select max(sal) as maxsal from emp where job='clerk') tempmax where  tempemp.sal > tempmax.maxsal and tempemp.job = 'salesman';
```

The above would give you names and salary of those employees who are salesman and have their salary more than max salary of all clerks.

Tested on Hive

Answer (score 0):

Quickly the SQL would be something like this

```
select ename,salary from employee where job = "SALESMAN" and Salary > 
( select max(salary) from employee where job = "CLERK" )
```

Note: This is not tested